# Iterating through list with multiple values and calculating the mean

Tags: python

I have the following list that I'd like to get the `measures` for each `id` and calculate weighted average for each time stamp:

```
[
   {
      "name":"SCB P10-CB-5-3-2",
      "id":"1d72ac1a-a50c-11e7-95ec-42010afa015a",
      "power":144.0,
      "measures":[
         [
            "20200322T103001Z",
            "6.0"
         ],
         [
            "20200322T103501Z",
            "6.0"
         ]
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"SCB P10-CB-6-3-9",
      "id":"1f778580-a50c-11e7-95ec-42010afa015a",
      "power":58.5,
      "measures":[
         [
            "20200322T103001Z",
            "2.0"
         ],
         [
            "20200322T103501Z",
            "2.0"
         ]
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"SCB P10-CB-5-2-6",
      "id":"1d49a464-a50c-11e7-95ec-42010afa015a",
      "power":144.0,
      "measures":[
         [
            "20200322T103000Z",
            "5.98"
         ],
         [
            "20200322T103500Z",
            "5.72"
         ]
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"SCB P10-CB-2-2-9",
      "id":"17f4cb10-a50c-11e7-95ec-42010afa015a",
      "power":76.8,
      "measures":[
         [
            "20200322T103001Z",
            "4.0"
         ],
         [
            "20200322T103501Z",
            "4.0"
         ]
   }
]
```

My goal is to iterate throught it and create a new vector with a specific formula: `(measures[1] * max(powerInDict)) / powerCurrentID` to compare each measure value from each time stamp with this calculated vector to see which `name` is below it.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Hello @AMC, I'd like to know if it's possible to do what I called as my "goal" on the last paragraph

Comment: Although I haven't looked at it in depth, it certainly seems possible.

Comment: Oh that is great! Could you please tell me how or give me a direction? I'm a python rookie and got kinda lost with this complex list

Answer (score 0):

Here it is something similar to I'd like to do, but I strongly believe that this is far from the best way to do it:

```
for i in range(0, len(responseRequest)):
    println(responseRequest[i])
    count = 0
    for medida in responseRequest[i]['measures']:
        println('%d - %s ,  %s' % (i, medida[1], responseRequest[i]['power']))
        weightedAverage[count] = weightedAverage[count] + responseRequest[i]['power']/medida[i]
        count = count + 1

weightedAverage = weightedAverage * max(responseRequest['power'])/(i+1)
println(weightedAverage)

# When  weightedAverage  is done, compare each timeStamp (each line) to the values inside  the list
```